# v-if inside v-for not working on click button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to show the proper template inside a v-for based on a v-if.

When a button is clicked should change the value which is contained in the v-if

```html
<div v-for="(items, index) in suppliers" :key="index">
  <v-btn @click="newSupplier[index].edit = true">Edit</v-btn>
  <template v-if="newSupplier[index].edit">
    // Display supplier information
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    // Display edit form
  </template>
<div>
```

newSupplier is an object which contain some informations included edit
suppliers is a data property which contain the (same) number of suppliers.

The code should trigger the v-if and display the proper template

Comment: And what does not work?

Comment: shoudn't `newSupplier ` be `suppliers`? make sure that `index` exist on that object and it has an edit prop with a boolean value

Comment: ```newSupplier``` and ```suppliers``` have the same indexes so i'm sure exist. The edit prop is a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set newSupplier using `Vue.set(newSupplier, index, value)` and not `newSupplier[index]=value`.

The indexing may cause your newSupplier to not be reactive.